# Not able to use SSL and TLS connections for mariadb clients

Tags: mysql, ssl, ssl-certificate, mariadb

Helo I a using MariaDB : Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB
I am trying to enable SSL- TLS for my database system.

Here are the configurations I have done so far:

In

> /etc/my.cnf

```
[mariadb]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql-ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql-ssl/server-key.pem
bind-address = *


[client-mariadb]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql-ssl/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql-ssl/client-key.pem
ssl-verify-server-cert
```

In MySQL console I am getting this  :

```
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                          |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                            |
| have_ssl      | YES                            |
| ssl_ca        | /etc/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem     |
| ssl_capath    |                                |
| ssl_cert      | /etc/mysql-ssl/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                                |
| ssl_key       | /etc/mysql-ssl/server-key.pem  |
+---------------+--------------------------------+


MariaDB [(none)]> STATUS;
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:          2
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         5.5.60-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 12 sec
```

What should I do so that my client uses the SSL / TLS connection ?

What configuration am I missing ?

There are three files under this folder : `/etc/my.cnf.d`

1. client.cnf
2. mysql-clients.cnf
3. server.cnf

Are there any changes I should be doing in any of these files ?

**Update :**

When I put the client configurations in my.cnf I get this error :

```
[client-mariadb]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql-ssl/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql-ssl/client-key.pem
```

> ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Comment: What is output of  ```mysql --help | grep ssl```  ? Can you connect to server with ```mysql --ssl``` ?

Comment: @GeorgRichter I get this :  ssl                               TRUE
ssl-ca                            /etc/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          /etc/mysql-ssl/client-cert.pem
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           /etc/mysql-ssl/client-key.pem
ssl-verify-server-cert            TRUE

Comment: And what about ```mysql --ssl``` ?

Comment: @GeorgRichter I get this error : ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Comment: Hmm, and the client you're using to connect to MariaDB server is mysql command line client - or is it some other application?

Comment: @GeorgRichter it is MySQL Command Line Client for now, But in real application it will be PHP-MySQL connector